# Vitest FormData error when trying to upload an image to Cloudinary

Tags: form-data, react-typescript, vitest

I'm currently taking a Udemy course on React, but I'm using vitest and TypeScript instead of Jest and JavaScript.

I'm encountering an issue with a `fileUpload` utility that uploads images to Cloudinary. While it works fine in the app, I'm facing an error when attempting to test the function. Cloudinary responds with the following error message: `{"error":{"message":"Upload preset must be specified when using unsigned upload"}}`.

fileUpload.ts

```js
export const fileUpload = async (file?: File) => {
  if (!file) throw new Error("There's no file selected for uploading");

  const cloudinaryCloudName = "dwalcv9li";
  const cloudUrl = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudinaryCloudName}/upload`;

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("upload_preset", "react-course");
  formData.append("file", file);

  try {
    const resp = await fetch(cloudUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    const responseBody = await resp.text();
    console.log({ responseBody });

    if (!resp.ok) throw new Error("It was not posible to update the image");
    const cloudResp = await resp.json();

    return cloudResp.secure_url;
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      throw new Error(error.message);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
};
```

fileUpload.test.ts

```js
import { describe, expect, it } from "vitest";
import { fileUpload } from "./fileUpload";

describe("fileUpload", () => {
  it("should throw an error if no file is selected", async () => {
    await expect(fileUpload()).rejects.toThrowError(
      "There's no file selected for uploading"
    );
  });

  it.only("should upload a file to Cloudinary successfully", async () => {
    const imageUrl =
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506744038136-46273834b3fb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80";
    const resp = await fetch(imageUrl);
    const blob = await resp.blob();
    const file = new File([blob], "foto.jpg");
    const result = await fileUpload(file);
    expect(typeof result).toBe("string");
  });
});
```

vite.config.ts

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
  },
});
```

I have tried different approaches found in internet, but none of them really are about the issue I'm facing. I also tried another fetch get functions and they work, is just when I use formData that it don't seem to work.